# How to render environment in Tensorforce?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, implementation

How can one render the environment using the Tensorforce library?

I've tried calling `environment.render`, but it says that the function does not exist. This is my code:

```
from tensorforce.agents import Agent
from tensorforce.environments import Environment
from tensorforce.execution import Runner

# Create an OpenAI-Gym environment
environment = Environment.create(environment='gym', level='MountainCarContinuous-v0')

agent = Agent.create(agent='random', environment=environment)   

# runner = Runner(agent=agent, environment=environment) # Initialize the runner
# runner.run(num_episodes=NUM_EPISODES) # Start the runner
# runner.close()

# Train
for ep in range(NUM_EPISODES): # Number of episodes

    print('********Episode ' + str(ep) + '********')

    # Initialize episode
    states = environment.reset()
    done = False
    step = 0

    while not done: # Episode timestep
        actions = agent.act(states=states)
        states, done, reward = environment.execute(actions=actions)
        agent.observe(terminal=done, reward=reward)
        environment.render() # Gives error

environment.close()
agent.close()
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\users\user\reinforcement learning\rl.py", line 179, in <module>
    environment.render()

AttributeError: 'OpenAIGym' object has no attribute 'render'
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you use
https://github.com/tensorforce/tensorforce/blob/master/examples/act_observe_interface.py ,
the following modification works.
Import gym:

```
import gym
from gym import wrappers
```

then define a Tensorforce environment with a Gym environment:

```
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
    env = wrappers.Monitor(env, 'tmp', force=True)

    environment = Environment.create(environment=env, max_episode_timesteps=500)
    # environment = Environment.create(environment='/Users/rondelion/git/tensorforce/benchmarks/configs/cartpole.json')
```

and render the Gym environment:

```
            ....
            num_updates += agent.observe(terminal=terminal, reward=reward)
            env.render()
            sum_rewards += reward
            ....
```